# How do I customize the screen definition?

Tags: javascript, function, screen, matchmedia

Good day!

Found a script on the network to determine the screen size, but I can not figure out how to correctly set the definition isMobile, isTablet, isDesktop.

```
function() {
    var i = {
        mobile: "mobile",
        tablet: "tablet",
        desktop: "desktop",
        oldHeight: null,
        oldWidth: null,
        current: function() {
            return this.define()
        },
        isMobile: function() {
            return this.define() === this.mobile
        },
        isTablet: function() {
            return this.define() === this.tablet
        },
        isDesktop: function() {
            return this.define() === this.desktop
        },
        define: function() {
            return this.width() < 768 ? this.mobile : this.width() < 1360 ? this.tablet : this.desktop
        },
        height: function() {
            return window.innerHeight
        },
        width: function() {
            return window.innerWidth
        },
        init: function() {
            this.oldHeight = window.innerHeight, this.oldWidth = this.define()
        }
    };
```

Tell me please...

Now I use this method:

```
if(
    (screen.width <= 640) || 
    (window.matchMedia && 
     window.matchMedia('only screen and (max-width: 640px)').matches
    )
  ){
   // Do the mobile thing
}
```

But I think that the above script is more universal.

P.S. Can eat more correct ways of definition of the sizes of the screen?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling the `isMobile` method? It seems to work fine if you remove the outer anonymous `function` and call the methods like `i.isMobile()` - for me that reports `false` when I have the browser maximized, and true if I shrink the browser down to less than 768px wide...

Comment: I got it, thank you.
Here so it works:

if (i.isMobile()) {
 pageMain.classList.add("main--hide");
}

Comment: If this answer helped you, please consider choosing it as the accepted answer, or giving it an upvote